# Amavis and SpamAssassin won't mark junk email as spam in second domain

Tags: spamassassin, amavis

I'm currently setting up amavis and spamassassin with postfix. So far SpamAssassin blocks and bounces Spam. If I set `$final_spam_destiny` to `D_PASS` the mail gets through, but the `$sa_spam_subject_tag` does not get attached and the X-Spam value does not exist either.

The log clearly states, that it passes Spam:

```
amavis[28391]: (28391-01) Passed SPAM, [209.***] [93.1***] <s**g@*.com> -> <*@s*.de>, quarantine: C/spam-CJpo9ylrA1wv.gz, Message-ID: <5006FC18.5090100@*.com>, mail_id: CJpo9ylrA1wv, Hits: 999.201, size: 2125, queued_as: 37D3C3148077, 4803 ms
```

Message header contains:

```
Return-Path: <*@*.com>
X-Original-To: *@*.de
Delivered-To: *@*.de
Received: from localhost (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by *.de (Postfix) with ESMTP id 37D3C3148077
    for <*@*.de>; Wed, 18 Jul 2012 20:10:43 +0200 (CEST)
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at *.de
Received: from *.de ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (*.de [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id CJpo9ylrA1wv for <*@*.de>;
    Wed, 18 Jul 2012 20:10:38 +0200 (CEST)
Received-SPF: pass ...
Received: from mail-bk0-f53.google.com (mail-bk0-f53.google.com [209.85.214.53])...
Received: by bkwj4 with SMTP id j4so1701207bkw.40...
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
    h=message-id:date:from:user-agent:mime-version:to:subject
     :content-type:content-transfer-encoding;
    bh=id84uDPa9SMZAVd+g2pYg3Hl9aPfnapoGlOygxrIuV4=;
    b=JIl4ACvkBlszuucl5FcvhGLv3zJxmxxcwXNrEfdow5hhzkxPdYuyiZ+l6ONNNYpQ/g
     S1rzFxK13JZ8meekXFZMjA6e+vDlngLjHgBqpT8lmYVAoc+XBsZQZmtVgchIRgVTckZ7
     yCoYKcR0uC4OW9PWZnCmM5gCnz/EUp/YpOZ/6cSRkZQCFoFyzdsMinC4vZObwvSviTlZ
     0Yg3NricaELpWH9umginV0rBH3XQzfVadkbfZFfmr2ZIt/bhVl1Gg9MR5rZ1hFcSotm+
     7JmpqetIoTRCr3lK41ePY26VbVf9doM3GczWrjZuG1jzv8xyUMKXs2SRQuWaM2X0CB7R
     +X9Q==
Received: by 10.205.123.9 with SMTP id gi9mr2278388bkc.50.1342635037852;
    Wed, 18 Jul 2012 11:10:37 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from [192.168.1.68] (srbk-5d801d46.pool.mediaWays.net. [93.128.29.70])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id t23sm12424175bks.4.2012.07.18.11.10.35
    (version=SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
    Wed, 18 Jul 2012 11:10:37 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: <*.*@gmail.com>
```

This happens only on my second domain. On the first domain Spamassassin works as expected.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it:

i added my second domain in the `amavis/conf.d/05-domain-id` file:

```
@local_domains_acl = ( ".$mydomain",".seconddomain.de" );
```

now it works.

Comment: thanks, this post helped me troubleshooting